# how to aggregate mean for a list and create a new matrix

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames and after partitioning some columns, I want to get a new data.frame with all the means. The example is as follows:

```
a=data.frame(ID=1:100,WT=1:100)
b=data.frame(ID=101:205,WT=101:205)
c=data.frame(ID=1001:1010,WT=1001:1010)
d=list(a,b,c)
names(d)=c("P01","P02","P03")
```

Then, I created two additional columns for each data frame

```
d2=lapply(d,transform,seq=seq_along(ID))  
d3=lapply(d2,transform,bin=cut(seq,20,1:20))
```

Now, I want to get the means in relation to the bin column. The following code shows how I did that for only one participant:

```
P01=aggregate(d3$P01$WT,list(d3$P01$bin),mean)  
P01$Participant="P01"
```

The new "P01" data.frame has three columns: the column called bin, then the means for the column WT and finally the participant's name.

My question is, how do I automatise this process, so I can get the dataframe of means with not only P01 but all other participants (i.e., P02 and P03)?
This data frame should have the three columns and the data for all participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
mylist <- sapply(names(d3), function(p){
  transform(aggregate(d3[[p]]$WT, list(d3[[p]]$bin), mean), Participant=p)
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

This gives a list with the three dataframes `P01`, `P02`, `P03`.

Then you can concatenate into one dataframe:

```
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Comment: Just to simplify - `lapply(d3, function(x) aggregate(WT~bin, x, mean))`